# how can i create an array of objects filled by the user and view the array elements?

Tags: java, arrays

I created a method to create an array of objects that will be filled by the user and another method to show the filled array. I'm having problems viewing the array and I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
public void addPlayer() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        System.out.println("player  " + (i + 1));
        System.out.println("Name:");
        String name = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Sweater number:");
        int sNr = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Card (red,null,yellow)");
        String card = scan.next();
        players[i]=new Player(name,sNr,card);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the "problems" in viewing the array ? any bug or what ? it's helpful if you state what is your problem

Comment: i have bugs in viewing the array once filled by the  user. when i click to view the array in the menu i created an error message saying "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"  appears and it points out to the line "       players[i]=new Player(name,sNr,card);"

Answer (score 1):

You can also take separate Player pojo class and setters,getters to set and get data.

```
package com.testapp.main;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Player {
        private String name;
        private int sNr;
        private String card;

        public Player() {

        }

        public Player(String name, int sNr, String card) {
            this.name = name;
            this.sNr = sNr;
            this.card = card;
        }


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Player [name=" + name + ", sNr=" + sNr + ", card=" + card + "]";
        }

        public void addPlayer() {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            Player players[] = new Player[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                System.out.println("player  " + (i + 1));
                System.out.println("Name:");
                name = scan.next();
                System.out.println("Sweater number:");
                sNr = scan.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Card (red,null,yellow)");
                card = scan.next();
                players[i] = new Player(name, sNr, card);
                System.out.println(players[i]);
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Player p = new Player();
            p.addPlayer();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and the problem viewing the array persists.  the exercise asks to create three classes. class player, class team and teamTest. i dont know if the problem has to do with the relations between the 3 classes.